# Update status in Jira ticket

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api

I have a python script for Jira integration. I create a ticket using API. I am able to update different fields in Jira ticket, but I am unable to update status in Jira via API. Do we have a field for that? Below is the code for creating issue.

```
execution_key = create_update_issue("ProjectName",summary,description,"Test Execution",)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jira **status** may be a field but it is not changing directly. You can change **status** via **transitions**.

You can use Rest API's `POST` request to the `/rest/api/2/issue/{issueKey}/transitions` endpoint with a suitable transition id.

```
curl -u username:password -X POST --data '{"transition":{"id":"11"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://jira/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-1/transitions
```

You can find a valid transition id from the `GET` `/rest/api/2/issue/{issueKey}` endpoint or you can check the workflow details in Jira UI.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. I got your point. Just wanted to know whether I will be able to change status/ transitions via XRAY module ??